# python: regex to extract content between two text

Tags: python, regex

I want a python regex expression that can pull the contents between `script["` and `"]` but there are other `"]"` which worries me

expected:
`{bunch of javascript here. [\"apple\"] test}`

my attempt:

`javascript\[\"(.*)"]`

target string:

`//url//script["{bunch of javascript here. [\"apple\"] test}"]|//*[@attribute="eggs"]`

[link to the regex](http://pythex.org/?regex=script%5C%5B%5C%22(.*)%22%5D&test_string=%2F%2Furl%2F%2Fscript%5B%22%7Bbunch%20of%20javascript%20here.%20%5B%5C%22apple%5C%22%5D%20test%7D%22%5D%7C%2F%2F*%5B%40attribute%3D%22eggs%22%5D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: Will this string contain multiple instances of this script[] that you want to match or just a single one?

Comment: @PaulThompson there is always only one script[] in between each `|`

Answer (score 1):

You can't match nested brackets with the re module since it doesn't have the recursion feature to do that. However, in your example you can skip the innermost square brackets if you choose to ignore all brackets enclosed between double quotes.

try something like this:

```
p = re.compile(r'script\["([^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)"]', re.S)
```

Note: I assumed here that the predicate is only related to the "text" content of the script node (and not an attribute, a number of item or an axe).

Comment: there is only one `script[]` in between each `|`. I want text between `script["` and `"]`

Comment: this looks good but I just need the content between `script["` and `"]`. this gives me the whole text

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand exactly what you want to achieve because of the way you have written the question. However if you are looking for the firs instance of `"]` AFTER a `}` then try this:

```
\["([^}]+}.*?)"\]
```

[Link to the regex](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5C%5B%22(%5B%5E%7D%5D%2B%7D.*%3F)%22%5C%5D&test_string=%2F%2Furl%2F%2Fscript%5B%22%7Bbunch%20of%20javascript%20here.%20%5B%5C%22apple%5C%22%5D%20test%7D%22%5D%7C%2F%2F*%5B%40attribute%3D%22eggs%22%5D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

This also would work:

```
 \["(.*?}.*?)"\]
```

[Link to the second regex example](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5C[%22%28.*%3F%7D.*%3F%29%22%5C]&test_string=%2F%2Furl%2F%2Fscript[%22%7Bbunch%20of%20javascript%20here.%20[%5C%22apple%5C%22]%20test%7D%22]%7C%2F%2F*[%40attribute%3D%22eggs%22]&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)